# Searching for and Moving Files Based on Part of the Filename

Tags: python, shutil

So i'm a QC for a software company and i'm currently stuck on a Python script i'm writing to sort through over 108,00 error logs. What i'm trying to do is filter out the reports that come from our previous and current release versions (4.1.468 and 4.1.478 respectively).

The reports appear with filenames like this(with MD for Mac Reports, and WD for Windows Reports):

4.1.468MD.OutOfBoundsException.RaiseOutOfBoundsException.1

The first part of my script works, looking for and creating folders (if they don't already exist) to copy the selected reports to. But the actual copying of the reports never happens.

Any advice or pointers you can offer would be greatly received.

```
import os
import shutil 
import time
import pprint
import csv
from collections import Counter

path = 'C:\Heavy Logging Reports\Recorded Issues'

names = os.listdir(path)


folder_name = ['468','478']
for x in range(0,2):
    if not os.path.exists(path+folder_name[x]):
        os.makedirs(path+folder_name[x])

dest1 = 'C:\Heavy Logging Reports\Recorded Issues468'
dest2 = 'C:\Heavy Logging Reports\Recorded Issues478'


for f in names:
    if (f[:4].startswith("468WD")):
        shutil.copy(path, dest1)

    elif (f[:4].startswith("478WD")):
        shutil.copy(path, dest2)


print('Finished Moving Files!')
```

Comment: It should be `f[4:]` instead of `f[:4]` I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help.

**Demo:**

```
import os
import shutil 
import time
import pprint
import csv
from collections import Counter

path = r'C:\Heavy Logging Reports\Recorded Issues'

names = os.listdir(path)


folder_name = ['468','478']
for x in folder_name:
    fPath = path+x
    if not os.path.exists(fPath):
        os.makedirs(fPath)

dest1 = 'C:\Heavy Logging Reports\Recorded Issues468'
dest2 = 'C:\Heavy Logging Reports\Recorded Issues478'


for f in names:
    if (f[4:].startswith("468WD")):
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(path, f), os.path.join(dest1, f))

    elif (f[4:].startswith("478WD")):
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(path, f), os.path.join(dest2, f))


print('Finished Moving Files!')
```

Comment: That works.

I assume if i wanted to move the files i could just replace shutil.copy with shutil.move?

Also, how do i set it to copy or move the 468WD and the 468MD files to the target folder?